# JMeter Results to Splunk

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, splunk, blazemeter

Is there any JMeter plugin available natively to send JMeter results to Splunk tcp forwarder? I looked up in jmeter-plugin's site but cannot find one. One other answer in SO suggested to use beanshell postprocessor to send the result. I am fairly new to Beanshell any help to get this done is much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of sending data to Splunk from JMeter you could do the opposite thing - configure Splunk's `input.conf` to read JMeter's .jtl results file. See [Monitor files and directories](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.6.3/Data/Monitorfilesanddirectories) article for more details.
2. Second viable choice would be sticking to JMeter [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler), I believe it is easier than using any form of scripting
3. If you are looking for a ready solution you can consider [SendToSplunk](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/sendtosplunk-send-text-data-splunk-tcp-port/) program which can be invoked via [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Hi Dimitri T, i am looking the 1st option.. is it possible?